# .java file saved in eclipse is filled with null charcters

Tags: java, eclipse

saved a .java file using eclipse and its filled with invalid characters and gibberish

at first I thought it was encoding wrong but I couldn't get it work no matter what I tried

this is the file when opened in notepad++ encoding using ANSI

```java
PK  :kךN               summerWork/.classpath}Kֲ0„ֿ
‏‡’»[½ץ׀*"¬ ױ«₪ֹR£qSע‎ק>PAo3ֳ·ֻL:<utBכ”¡ץ¡ַ"$a₪¢:cכrׂM״p׀i§Bsחמw7׃z;$o/ׁA‘ּ˜0ִ¢{˜1ck@¡Uדצׂƒזִמצfֻ|;^וhZהֻר›Sהׁ׳ ±
חִֿwO,~®
ֵ‘ W*צ•ה‚,[—¯ lיֶאֵ³™Lzֻ¢²[י´@rיj%÷-רh¢]wחָ^ֹ)ֹ“p+|‘$… t&ּq!–ׂX0E{k„yCd¼ן
¢5C±צ¨8L¢:…ן‚׳Mצשָןק^ׂ—$ר״ֱI`/ 0¥…·ןֶבֶ½7XˆFׁT‡³-«at¡ׂדֿן/¯gg׳׃׃ֵס¯}ו¿y¼$װכ{€•נ?`jװ¬~zִא־$:לת־טOH€$3Y²ׁjשֲPK$›?H  ר  PK   :kךNhJ¹   -                   summerWork/.classpathPK   :kךNB ¨%ְ   ‚                  summerWork/.projectPK   :kךNֻץb¾   V  /             ‎  summerWork/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefsPK   qODPH  ¼  &               summerWork/bin/summerWork/myOval.classPK   –OֻZ
ָ  ÷  )             ´  summerWork/bin/summerWork/myPicture.classPK   qOPגּ₪ז    %             ׃    summerWork/src/summerWork/myOval.javaPK   –O$›?H  ר  (               summerWork/src/summerWork/myPicture.javaPK      5  ×
```

never encountered this before and was wondering if there was a way to fix it because it would be really inconvenient to redo this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PK` at the start of the file, together with recognizable file names showing in between gibberish, is a good indication that you're actually looking at a **zip archive**.

Try renaming the file to *something*.zip and attempt to look at it with your favorite way to unpack zip files.